# Stop event bubbling in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I have a MovieClip which contains 4 Buttons:

[image: resolutions]

When the user mouses out of the container, it should disappear:

```
this.resolutions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, this.resolutionsClose);
```

When the user mouses out of any of the 4 Buttons, the event bubbles up to the container. This is not the expected behavior. How do I stop this propagation when none of the 4 Buttons have mouse out handlers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for the MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT event on the container.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 solutions (plus the one suggested by TandemAdam) :

1 - use the useCapture parameter

```
this.resolutions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, this.resolutionsClose, true);
```

You will receive the event when it's drilling down in the display list instead of bubbling up, so your container will dispatch before its children.

2 - Check in your event handler if event.target is your container :

```
private function onMouseOut(e:Event):void
{
    if(e.target == this.resolutions){
    // the original dispatcher was your resolutions container.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your buttons children of the container. Or on your buttons, listen for the same event, and call stopImmediatePropagation() on it.

Comment: It's convenient that the buttons are children of the container, so that when the container moves, the buttons move along with it. Are you sure attaching MOUSE_OUT listeners on the 4 buttons is the cleanest way to do it? What if this were a more complicated example with many more elements and much more nesting?